# Which test is useful to assess if a source is the same in two samples of binary data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, binary-data

I am looking for a statistical test that assesses if two samples which have binary values come from the same source or from different ones.

Example:

I have one set that has 10 0s and 6 1s and another set which has 50 0s and 29 1s. I would like to test the two sets from belonging from the same source or are significantly different. What is the best one? Is t-test appropriate for this specific case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classical contingency table, where you would test independence with a standard chi-squared test. In R:

```
chisq.test(cbind(c(10,6),c(50,29)))
```

(*Please* don't do t-tests on discrete data. Every time you do this, a kitten dies...)